# Compare column values of two dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python so please go easy. I have been looking up similar threads but unable to find a neat solution for my problem:

I want to compare column values of two data frames and put the values where different in a new data frame
my data frames are below and are different in lenghth(i.e. number of rows). I want to compare Status for each SKU:

```
df1

SKU PRICE   Status
A   1798    0
C   1798    1
D   999     0
E   1299    1
F   999     0


df2

SKU PRICE   Status
A   1798    1
B   2997    1
C   1798    1
D   999     0
```

Comparing df2 with df1 I am want to get following df3

```
SKU PRICE Status
A   1798  0
```

I know it can be done via loops but I am hoping there is a better solution via pandas or itertools out there?

Thanks for your help

df1:
[image]

df2:
[image]

Comment: Your expected output looks a bit off. Can you please double-check it?

Comment: What is the expected result here? To return matching SKU-price rows where the status differs? This sounds like a merge problem with an extra step: `df1.merge(df2, on=['SKU', 'PRICE']).query('Status_x != Status_y')`

Comment: Hello, Status for SKU A only has changed. Hence expecting only one row in the new DF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple merge and filtering operation:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['SKU', 'PRICE']).query('Status_x != Status_y')

  SKU  PRICE  Status_x  Status_y
0   A   1798         0         1
```

Or, more accurately:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=['SKU', 'PRICE'], suffixes=('', '_y'))
    .query('Status != Status_y')
    .drop('Status_y', 1))

  SKU  PRICE  Status
0   A   1798       0
```

Comment: wow, thank you seems to have done the trick. I have more than 4000 rows. So will run others checks to ensure result is right.But it looks great on first glance.

Comment: @failsafe100 sticking to your username, that's the right spirit.